# Spring Boot Actuator - override management.context-path for one actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to have a common prefix for most of my actuator endpoints.

I understand I can set a common prefix using `management.context-path`, e.g. `/actuator`. In that case, my http://localhost:8080/actuator will spit out links like

`self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/actuator"
},
info: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/actuator/info"
},
env: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/actuator/env"
},`

However, I would like to suppress/change that prefix for one of them, say `info`, so the link is `http://localhost:8080/other/info`, while all others remain intact.

I know I can do it by setting all `endpoints.*.path` properties, but I don't want to do that. I'd like to make one change only. I'd also be happy if my chosen endpoint had two mappings.

Is that possible? I'm on Boot 1.4.1, have debugged the code, and didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Can't you adjust it by setting `endpoints.info.path`? And leaving all the others to `/actuator/...`</strike>

EDIT: Okay I tested the approach above and did not work. You could implement an redirect like so:

```
@GetMapping("/info")
public String info() {
    return "redirect:/actuator/info";
}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, it would work indeed. The problem is that I have a lot of apps that need this functionality and modifying centralised system properties passed to every app is much preferred over code changes.

Comment: Why do you need them on different paths? Maybe you can add some background to the problem @maciej

Comment: Health endpoint is already exposed at a given path and consumed by various tools. All other endpoints will now be exposed (they're all disabled now) and need to be exposed on a different path, so we can restrict access to them based on paths. When that's done, I don't want to affect all the tools checking the health endpoint - that needs to continue working as is. So the health endpoint is the one that will have a different path to all others.

Comment: Okay, well i guess there is atleast 3 options.
1. the approach you mentioned yourself, modifying the path for all endpoints except health
2. You could enable [management security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions) or enable [endpoint sensitivity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-sensitive-endpoints) for other endpoints
3. Implement restrictions outside of spring. e.g. load balancer

Comment: I have already modified the path for all, since that was the fastest way. If that proves hard to maintain, I'll probably modify the config of our load balancers.

Thanks!